# Shake gesture not working on physical device with react native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am using react native version 0.38 and somehow the shake gesture, which is bringing up the developer menu has stopped working.

The devices is connected, and I already reversed the 8081 port. The adb shell command for keyevent input (adb shell input keyevent 82 or KEYCODE_MENU) is bringing up the background running applications.

The device is a Xiaomi redmi 3 with 5.1.1.

Any ideas how can I bring up the developer menu?

Comment: You could try: https://github.com/niftylettuce/frappe

But as far as I know this just a utility to send keyevent 82 as well. So if it doesn't work manually, this utility might not help either.

Comment: hey, did you find the solution for this problem?

Comment: Same here... just stopped on my s8+. ERG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Xiaomi devices you always have to enable the shake gesture in the options for your app. Although I still don't know which keycode can you use with adb on Xiaomi devices.

Answer (score 11):

On android, you should be able to open the dev menu by "Long" pressing the 'Overview' button (the square).

Comment: It is launching the assistant by "Long" pressing the 'Overview' button on my Xiaomi phone :(

Comment: long pressing is manufacturer/brand specific behavior. On my samsung it works by long pressing the back button.

Answer (score 1):

for xiaomi or poco you guys can try with long press back button! Works in poco c3